# Create or Update SharePoint ListItem with hyperlink field

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am unable to create or update a SharePoint Online `listitem` that contains a hyperlink field using Microsoft Graph. I can create or update items to the same list if I remove the hyperlink field from the body of the API call.

For update, I am sending a PATCH request to:

```
/v1.0/sites/<site>/list/<listid>/items/<item>/fields
```

with the following headers:

```
"Authorization" : "Bearer <token>"
"accept" :"application/json;odata.metadata=full;odata.streaming=true"
```

Here is the body:

```json
{
    "myUrl": {
        "Description": "http://www.google.com",
        "Url": "http://www.google.com"
    }
}
```

I will get the following error message in response:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "The request is malformed or incorrect.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "cfe30f57-31ba-4341-89e9-2c1bd4e15539",
            "date": "2017-11-10T21:55:30"
        }
    }
}
```

It is worth noting that I can update other fields in the list item using the exact headers and target URL, as long as there is not a hyperlink field in the json body.

The format I am sending is the exact format I receive the URL field in when I do a `GET`.  Does anyone know the appropriate format for sending URL fields back to SharePoint?

### Update 1/8/2018

I posted this same issue to Microsoft's Graph Github on 11/11/2017 and they have yet to provide an answer. I have heard unofficially that REST operations on listitems that have a nested structure (e.g. hyperlink, user, taxonomy) are not supported at this time.  Here is a link to the issue just in case they answer it later: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/1965

I do have a workaround for hyperlink fields that I am using.  I changed the column on the SharePoint List that was previously a hyperlink to a "Single line of text" field.  When a hyperlink is entered in a Single line text field, it is showing as a underlined and clickable link when you view the event in a browser.  You can't use alternate text if you have a long and ugly URL like with the hyperlink field type, but it works!

Comment: Can you add the full HTTP request including headers?

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for the reply.  I have updated the question to include some more supporting details and the headers of the request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Sharepoint REST API v1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service) to create or update the URL:

First, retrieve all properties of the file with a GET request to `<yourSharepointUrl>/sites/<site>/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='<filepath>')/ListItemAllFields`

Make sure to include your token for authentication. Also add the following two headers:

```http
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
```

Note down the value of the etag field in `d.__metadata.etag` in the JSON response.

Then, you can update the URL using a POST request to the same URL.

Besides the authentication header, include the following headers:

```http
Content-Type: application/json;odata=verbose
X-HTTP-Method: MERGE
If-Match: <etag>
```

Replace the etag tag with the value from the previous request. Make sure to keep the quotes!

The body of the request should look like this:

```json
{
    "__metadata": {
      "type": "SP.Data.Shared_x0020_DocumentsItem"
    },
    "myUrl": {
      "__metadata": {
        "type": "SP.FieldUrlValue"
      },
      "Description": "Link",
      "Url": "https://www.example.com"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the original poster mentioned, the workaround was to create a new (or change existing) column to single line up text.

To enhance his comment, you could then add conditional formatting to that column so that it becomes a clickable WITH alternate text.  Link provided below.

If you don’t have to use Graph, PnPListItem cmdlet works well.  You just need to use a command

Set-PnPListItem ……. -Values = @{myUrl=“https://link.com,Link”}

It still blows my mind how bad the implementation of Graph is.

[Link here](https://lists.handsontek.net/convert-single-line-text-column-hyperlink-using-sharepoint-microsoft-lists-column-formatting/%20https://)