# Cannot create SharePoint list item through Graph API which includes URL value

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to add more items when I create a SharePoint list item via the Graph API, including one which contains a URL.  I am using an HTTP POST request to pass a JSON payload to the correct endpoint located at [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{my_site_id}/lists/{my_list_id}/items](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bmy_site_id%7D/lists/%7Bmy_list_id%7D/items).  I can POST successfully to this list so long as I do not try to add the URL fields.  All other items in this list are simple key/value pairs.  However, if you GET an existing list item, the field shows up as the following nested data structure:  with the title "Security_x0020_Survey_x0020_url," which exists as:

```
{  
    "fields":  
    {  
        [many more items],  
        "Security_x0020_Survey_x0020_url": 
        {
            "Description": "https://[my_url_goes_here]",
            "Url": "https://[my_url_goes_here]"
        }
        [many more items]
    }
}
```

But when you try to POST a JSON payload which includes this field using a patch document which matches this exact format, it blows up with an HTTP 400 "Invalid Request." No further information to be had other than "Invalid Request" to say why it is, in fact, invalid.

How am I supposed to create a list item which includes data for this field?

HTTP POST request to [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{my_site_id}/lists/{my_list_id}/items](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bmy_site_id%7D/lists/%7Bmy_list_id%7D/items) with a JSON payload including the field listed above. Expected to receive an HTTP 2XX response with the typical information from Microsoft Graph showing item creation. Did receive an HTTP 400 "Invalid Request" with no further amplifying info about what, in fact, was invalid. Request will complete successfully when not including the "Security_x0020_Survey_x0020_url" field in the JSON payload.

Comment: I'm afraid that creating hyperlink column via Graph API is still not supported. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs-contrib/issues/663

Comment: I think it is not supported using MS graph API. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47231751/create-or-update-sharepoint-listitem-with-hyperlink-field) and [this](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-php/issues/1445).